# How to run multiple specs parallel with single conf.js?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, browserstack

I've splitted my project from one huge test to a few smaller to speed up tests and avoid some errors. Is there any way to run all of them parallel with single conf file? I must pass through login.js before every testcase
specs: ['login.js', 'test1.js'],

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878732/unable-to-launch-multiple-browser-instances-in-protractor/54878887#54878887> Hope it helps you

Comment: Do you have multiple describe blocks in any of your new tests?

Comment: @DublinDev yes, every test is splited - describe blocks for main menu, adding, viewing, cloning and deleting, then every describe is splited to it blocks containing expects

Comment: @Madhan thx, but i can't disable login to site, so i must then paste this login spec to my every new spec file to work it properly?

Comment: @CzescTuSlawomr Create suite and run them in separate browsers. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331018/suites-vs-specs-protractor

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your login.js spec into a file which exports a login function. Then create a beforeAll in your onPrepare in your conf. This will be executed before every describe block, which in your case is every test.

```
onPrepare: function {
    beforeAll(function(){
        loginToApp();           
    });
};
```

I know you have already split up the files but I would seriously consider using the [page object model](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings) to structure your tests if you have the time.